# Sqlite SQL query to include empty groups

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

This might be trivial, but my SQL literacy is limited.

Suppose, you have two tables in a database. Here are the queries to construct and fill them with data:

```
CREATE TABLE `participiants` (
    `name`  TEXT,
    `age`   INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE `outcomes` (
    `participiant`  TEXT,
    `score` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO participiants
VALUES('Alice', 15),
    ('Bob', 37),
    ('Cindy', 56);

INSERT INTO outcomes
VALUES('Alice', 200),
    ('Alice', 250),
    ('Cindy', 180);
```

The tables with data look like this

participiants

```
name    age
------------
Alice   15
Bob     37
Cindy   56
```

outcomes

```
participiant   score
---------------------
Alice          200
Alice          250
Cindy          180
```

For every participiants.name I would like to query their MAX(outcomes.score), including the empty group for Bob who is not present in the outcomes table, so the resulting set should look like this:

```
participiants.name   MAX(outcomes.score)
-----------------------------------
Alice                 250
Bob                   NONE
Cindy                 180
```

I have tried

```
SELECT participiants.name, MAX(outcomes.score)
FROM participiants, outcomes
WHERE participiants.name = outcomes.participiant
GROUP BY participiants.name
```

but, of course, this won't include Bob NONE. What SQL/Sqlite syntax should I look into, to find the solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT participiants.name, MAX(outcomes.score)
FROM participiants
LEFT JOIN outcomes
ON participiants.name = outcomes.participiant
GROUP BY participiants.name
```

`LEFT JOIN` will select all the elements from table "PARTICIPANTS"

Comment: I came up with the exact same solution a minute ago, after I looked into LEFT JOIN on a sqlite tutorial page. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a left outer join:

```
 SELECT participiants.name, MAX(outcomes.score)
 FROM participiants LEFT OUTER JOIN outcomes on participiants.name = outcomes.participiant
 GROUP BY participiants.name
```